# Definition lists in kramdown

Tags: kramdown

How do I generate the following HTML markup using kramdown?

```
<ol>
<li> <dt> Term </dt> 
<dd class="meta">  Definition of the term </dd> 
</li>
</ol>
```

where the `meta` is some appropriate styling (class) defined in my css.

> I already tried:
>
> ```
> 1. Term 
> : Definition of the term {: .meta}
> ```
>
> but that does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably getting the following error:

```
Warning: Found span IAL after text - ignoring it
```

If you therefore put the IAL before the text, it parses fine.

```
1. Term
: {: .meta} Definition of the term
```

yields

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt>Term</dt>
      <dd class="meta">Definition of the term</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
</ol>
```