# Add CSS class to definition list in kramdown

Tags: kramdown

How can I add a CSS class to a definition list generated by kramdown? Like the HTML sample below.
For background, the reason I want to do this is to style it with [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#horizontal-description)'s *dl-horizontal* class.

```
<dl class="my-stylish-class">
    <dt>Term</dt>
    <dd>Definition</dd>
</dl>
```

I've tried the below, but no matter where I put `{: .my-stylish-class}`, the class always gets attached to the definition term or definition element, and never the list itself.

```
{: .my-stylish-class}
1. Term
: Definition
```

I have seen the post [Definition lists in kramdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146425/definition-lists-in-kramdown), but that is asking about adding a class to a definition element `<dd>`, not the list itself `<dl>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a solution that worked for me after posting. Putting the class at the end of the list will attach it to the list (or surrounding container) itself.

```
1. Term
: Definition

2. Another Term
: Another definition
{: .my-stylish-class}
```

Will result in either:

```
<dl class="my-stylish-class">
    <dt>Term</dt>
    <dd>Definition</dd>
    <dt>Another Term</dt>
    <dd>Another definition</dd>
</dl>
```

or

```
<ol class="my-stylish-class">
    <li>
        <dl>
            <dt>Term</dt>
            <dd>Definition</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
    <li>
        <dl>
            <dt>Another Term</dt>
            <dd>Another definition</dd>
        </dl>

    </li>
</ol>
```

The first sample was generated by kramdown in [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), whereas the second sample was generated by an [online kramdown generation service](http://kramdown.herokuapp.com/). I don't know why there is a difference between the generated HTML of the two; perhaps they are different versions of kramdown or specific settings in my flavor of jekyll.